# Prove that two regular curves are orthogonal if and only if $E\phi_v\psi_v-F(\phi_u\psi_v+\phi_v\psi_u)+G\phi_u\psi_u=0$.

Tags: differential-geometry

If $\phi (u,v)=C_1$, $\psi(u,v)=C_2$ are regular curves on a surface. Prove that they are orthogonal if and only if
$$E\phi_v\psi_v-F(\phi_u\psi_v+\phi_v\psi_u)+G\phi_u\psi_u=0.$$

Here $E,F,G$ are the coefficients of
the first fundamental form of surface.

> By calculating the complete differential of $\phi(u,v)$ and $\psi(u,v)$, if $\phi_v$ and $\phi_u$ don't equal to 0 at $t_0$, (and $\psi$ have the same properties), the proposition is not hard to prove. My problem is  when facing the situation $\phi_v$ and $\phi_u$ equal to 0 at the same time, I cannot find the relationship between $\frac{du}{dt}$ and $\frac{dv}{dt}$. (btw it looks like I have not used that the two curves are regular :(  Could anyone help me solve the problem? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Coefficient of $F$ is positive?  i.e., $E\phi_v\psi_v+F(\phi_u\psi_v+\phi_v\psi_u)+G\phi_u\psi_u=0?$

Comment: @Narasimham No, you're wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that their regularity hypothesis is that at each point of the level curves, one of $\phi_u,\phi_v$ is nonzero and one of $\psi_u,\psi_v$ is nonzero. (So what you were worried about should not ever occur.) I'm going to assume that your surface is parametrized by $\mathbf x(u,v)$, so that $\mathbf x_u$ and $\mathbf x_v$ span the tangent plane at each point.

I think the easiest approach is to see that the tangent vector to the first level curve is (a nonzero scalar multiple of) $X=\phi_v \mathbf x_u - \phi_u \mathbf x_v$ and the tangent vector of the second level curve is, likewise, $Y= \psi_v \mathbf x_u - \psi_u \mathbf x_v$. Now compute the inner product of $X$ and $Y$ using the first fundamental form.